# Iterating through enum value in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have the below code

```
enum class State {
    EMPTY, LOADING, DATA, ERROR
}
private var currentState = State.EMPTY

private var timer: Timer? = null

fun startTimer() {
    if (timer == null) {
        timer = fixedRateTimer(period = 1000, action = {

            mainvView.showView(currentState)
            currentState = when (currentState) {
                State.EMPTY -> State.LOADING
                State.LOADING -> State.DATA
                State.DATA -> State.ERROR
                State.ERROR -> State.EMPTY
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Where it iterates through the enum in a fixed interval of 1s.

I don't particularly like this piece

```
            currentState = when (currentState) {
                State.EMPTY -> State.LOADING
                State.LOADING -> State.DATA
                State.DATA -> State.ERROR
                State.ERROR -> State.EMPTY
            }
```

As I was hoping more towards something below, so I don't need to explicitly write out all the state transition

```
            if (currentState == State.ERROR) {
                currentState = State.EMPTY
            } else {
                currentState++
            }
```

Obviously `currentState++` is not possible. Is there other way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like `currentState++` if you use operator overloading like

```
operator fun State.inc(): State = when(this){
            State.EMPTY -> State.LOADING
            State.LOADING -> State.DATA
            State.DATA -> State.ERROR
            State.ERROR -> State.EMPTY
        }
```

Or if just want to circle through the enum

```
operator fun State.inc(): State {
             val size = State.values().size
             return State.values()[(this.ordinal + 1) % size]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use generic function

```
inline operator fun <reified E : Enum<E>> E.inc() =
    enumValues<E>()[(ordinal + 1) % enumValues<E>().size]
```